# How to write docker command with /bin/sh and assign result to variable?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, sh

I am trying to write a shell script that should start a docker container.
I have a running example, but it uses `/bin/bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export NETWORK=jetty-svc-test
export IMAGE_TAG=jetty-test-app
export SVC_NAME=svc-test

clean_up() {
    docker stop $SVC_NAME
    docker network rm $NETWORK
}

docker network create $NETWORK
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

docker build --tag $IMAGE_TAG .
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

docker run -it --rm --name $SVC_NAME --network=$NETWORK -v $(pwd)/app:/app -d $IMAGE_TAG
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
sleep 5

export RES=$(docker run --rm --network=$NETWORK curlimages/curl:7.71.1 http://$SVC_NAME:8080 | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq .)
export HEALTH_CHECK=$(echo "$RES" | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq -r .status)

if [ "$HEALTH_CHECK" != "I am healthy" ]; then
    clean_up
    exit 1
fi

clean_up
```

but I need it in `#!/bin/sh`. For instance, the statement `export RES=$(..` does not work in `#!/bin/sh`.

I need to rewrite the script above, because https://hub.docker.com/layers/docker/library/docker/19.03.12/images/sha256-d208a88b6afa09430a2f4becbc8dbe10bfdaeb1703f9ff3707ca96e89358a8e4?context=explore only supports `#!/bin/sh` and I would like to run the script above inside the docker:dind container.

How to write docker command with /bin/sh and assign result to variable?

Comment: Isn't `/bin/sh` usually symlinked to `bash` (or `dash` on debian-based systems, or `zsh` on macos)

Comment: I have rewritten my post.

Comment: `export RES=$(.. does not work in #!/bin/sh`? What does it mean "not work"? Please first check your script with shellcheck.net `if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then` is an  antiipattern, do `if ! command args args args; then`.

Comment: You can also try with back-ticks: `FOO=\`docker run ...\``.

Comment: @jakub Aren't you answering your own question? `/bin/sh` is often symlinked to *something,* but that *something*  is a moving target. `dash` is pretty close to a bare-bones POSIX `sh`.  `zsh` is a completely separate can of worms (though it can be set up to emulate both `bash` and `sh`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to rewrite

```
export variable=$(command)
export other="value"
```

and the answer for POSIX `sh` is simply

```
variable=$(command)
export variable

other="value"
export other
```

See also [Where is “export var=value” not available? *(on Unix / Linux Stack Exchange)*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available).

Comment: You should probably also learn to quote your variables. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can check the script again [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), I am not going to address the issue in shell script, as a suggestion in comment should work, but I will just to create a custom image by extending `docker:dind`, which will have `bash` as well as other utility that you are trying pull docker image for `jq` etc,

By doing this approach you will save network bandwidth plus CPU time.

```
FROM docker:dind
RUN apk add --no-cache bash jq curl
```

Now run this `docker:dind` image instead of the offical image, your script will become something like

```
docker run -dit --rm --name $SVC_NAME -p 3000:3000 --network=$NETWORK  jetty-test-app:latest
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
sleep 2

RES=$(curl localhost:3000/users | jq .)

export HEALTH_CHECK=$(echo "$RES" | jq .status)

if [ "$HEALTH_CHECK" != "I am healthy" ]; then
    clean_up
    exit 1
fi
clean_up
```